# C++ program implementing tree stops working when a node is inserted and I can't understand why

Tags: c++, tree

here is my code. after reading T the program reads the first input data and stops working. message "Unhandled exception at 0x00844D30 in tree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." is shown. I included iostream and stddef.h libraries.

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

class Solution{
public:
    Node* insert(Node* root, int data){
        if (root = NULL){
            return new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            Node* cur;
            if (data <= root->data){
                cur = insert(root->left, data);
                root->left = cur;
            }
            else{
                cur = insert(root->right, data);
                root->right = cur;
            }
            return root;
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    Solution myTree;
    Node* root = NULL;
    int T, data;
    cin >> T;
    while (T-->0){
        cin >> data;
        root = myTree.insert(root, data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you reformat your code, it is unreadable.

Comment: And what is the problem with the code? Please include the problem description *in the question body* (please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Also, have you tried to debug the program? What does the debugger say? Where does it stop (if it does)?

Comment: `Node(int d) : data(a), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {} ` would be better

Comment: Have you thought about using smart pointers?

Comment: Also check your comparisons, not all your comparisons are actually comparing things.

Comment: You say you _inserted iostream and stddef.h libraries_ by which I think you mean `#include`s, but I don't see them in the code. It helps if the code actually compiles to check what is wrong.

Comment: This statement `while (T-->0){` would be better as a `for` loop and also be more readable

Comment: `if (root = NULL){` should be `if (root == NULL){`

Comment: Also pick a better name than `Solution`

Comment: Perhaps adding some prompts and checking that integers are entered would make the system more user friendly

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be

> if (root==NULL)

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
using namespace std;
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

class Solution{
public:
    Node* insert(Node* root, int data){
        if(root == NULL){
            return new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            Node* cur;
            if (data <= root->data){
                cur = insert(root->left, data);
                root->left = cur;
            }
            else{
                cur = insert(root->right, data);
                root->right = cur;
            }
            cur->left=cur->right=NULL;
            return root;
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    Solution myTree;
    Node* root = NULL;
    int T, data;
    cin>>T;
    while (T-->0){
        cin>>data;
        root = myTree.insert(root, data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps changing the while loop to a for loop would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

This if will always go into the else part. Because you assign NULL to the variable root and then check the value. It should be `root == NULL`

```
        if (root = NULL){
            return new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            Node* cur;
            if (data <= root->data){
                cur = insert(root->left, data);
                root->left = cur;
            }
            else{
                cur = insert(root->right, data);
                root->right = cur;
            }
            return root;
        }
```

Comment: No prob :-) give an upvote for the two answers in here to show your love <3 :D